# Partial view not working on ajax call mvc5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

> i am working on view which is actually create view for customer.
>
> On "Create" View, I am using textbox to search the items from db and then display their detail on _part(Partial View)...The partial view action is correctly getting string and processing request except displaying partial view data on create view....

**Create View:**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="enginNo" />
    <input type="button" value="search" id="btnSearch" />
</form>
<div id="info" class="col-md-10">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("hola");
        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
            alert("hola2");
            var enginNo = $('#enginNo').val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    alert:("ajax called"),
                    type: 'Get',
                    data: { enginNo: enginNo },
                    url: '@Url.Action("CheckRecord")',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#result').html(result);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Returning string "enginNo" to partial view action below:**

```
public PartialViewResult CheckRecord(string enginNo)
{
    ViewBag.records = db.StockDMs.Where(ve => ve.EngineNumber == enginNo);
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_part", ViewBag.records);

    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

**PartialView:**

```
@model SM.CRM.AutosLoan.Models.Core.DomainModels.StockDM

<div>
    @{
        Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/SMClient.cshtml";
    }
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.records)
     {
     <dd>
                @item.AutoCompanyBrand.Name
            </dd>

            <dd>
                @item.SMClientBranch.Name
            </dd>
     }
```

**I don't know what i am doing wrong, thought if somebody help..Thanks for your time:-)**

Comment: what is your `_part` model type?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am not sure what you mean by model type,,, its strongly typed with StockDm Model

Comment: you should have not passed viewbag as an object model instead return as- `ViewBag.records="somedata" return PartialView("_part");`

Comment: not working yet.....could that be library reference problem also??

Comment: May be No! Can you edit question for what is inside partial view ?

Comment: internal server error [500],,, sorry i am now looking for that..

Comment: it looks more of a route problem,,,, beacuse the url should be same but it give error about http://localhost:44206/Sales/CheckRecord?enginNo=werr123 in console

Comment: what error? is it like `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[something.Models.Dynamic] but this dictionary requires a model item of type something.Models.StockDM` ?

Comment: actually db.StockDMs.Where(ve => ve.EngineNumber == enginNo) is returning IQueryable type and your view is looking for SM.CRM.AutosLoan.Models.Core.DomainModels.StockDM type. you can remove header line from your view to get expected results and also try to user extension ToList with where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PartialViewResult is returning html so, give `dataType:'HTML'` in your ajax request as shown:-

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'Get',
      data: { enginNo: enginNo },
      url: '@Url.Action("CheckRecord")',
      dataType: 'HTML',  // add this line
      success: function (result) {
             $('#result').html(result);
      }
 });
```

Comment: thanks for reply, still not displaying result, am i using partial view rightly??

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan...just add a error callback also in ajax request and check the error.

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan...there is some error in your partial view just put breakpoint there and debug every line of partial view.

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan... Instead of `@model SM.CRM.AutosLoan.Models.Core.DomainModels.StockDM` use `@model IEnumerable<SM.CRM.AutosLoan.Models.Core.DomainModels.StockDM>`